# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" When trying to attach a handler to an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to attach a JQuery plugin to a JQuery template. I've pretty much figured it out, except attaching a handler to the `confirm` and `cancel` events for this plugin.

The plugin is from here:https://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/

Working Code:

```
  <script id="buttonsTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <div class="col-md-6">
      <button type="button" id="enterInPTPButton" class="btn btn-primary" style="border-radius: 0; margin-left:10px; border-color:#3C5B75;">Entered In PTP</button>
      <button type="button" id=${'deleteEntryButton' + rowName} class="btn btn-warning confirm" style="border-radius: 0; margin-left:10px;">Delete Entry</button>
      <button type="button" id="offboardedButtons" class="btn btn-info" style="border-radius: 0; margin-left:10px; border-color:#3A7B8E;">Offboarded</button>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var rowName = "#deleteEntryButton";
      rowName = ${rowName};
      $(rowName).confirm({
          text: "Are you sure you want to delete this entry?",
          title: "Confirmation Required",
          confirmButton: "Yes I am",
          cancelButton: "No",
          confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
          cancelButtonClass: "btn-default"       
      });
 {{html "</sc"+"ript>"}}
 </script>
```

Non-working code:

```
  <script id="buttonsTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <button type="button" id="enterInPTPButton" class="btn btn-primary" style="border-radius: 0; margin-left:10px; border-color:#3C5B75;">Entered In PTP</button>
          <button type="button" id=${'deleteEntryButton' + rowName} class="btn btn-warning confirm" style="border-radius: 0; margin-left:10px;">Delete Entry</button>
          <button type="button" id="offboardedButtons" class="btn btn-info" style="border-radius: 0; margin-left:10px; border-color:#3A7B8E;">Offboarded</button>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          var rowName = "#deleteEntryButton";
          rowName = ${rowName};
          $(rowName).confirm({
              text: "Are you sure you want to delete this entry?",
              title: "Confirmation Required",
              confirm: function(button) {
                  DeleteEntry();
              },
              cancel: function(button) {
                  // nothing to do
              },
              confirmButton: "Yes I am",
              cancelButton: "No",
              confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
              cancelButtonClass: "btn-default"       
          });
     {{html "</sc"+"ript>"}}
  </script>
```

As soon as I add the following it stops working:

```
    confirm: function(button) {
        DeleteEntry();
    },
   cancel: function(button) {
        // nothing to do
    },
```

This code does seem to work on static elements though. What's causing this and what can I do to fix this?

Edit: Here is the full error in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of inputn.extend.globalEval @
>   jquery.js:328n.fn.extend.domManip @
>   jquery.js:5435jQuery.fn.extend.domManip @
>   jquery.tmpl.js:105n.fn.extend.append @
>   jquery.js:5218jQuery.fn.(anonymous function) @
>   jquery.tmpl.js:60FillTables @ userCodeAppPanel:119(anonymous function)
>   @ userCodeAppPanel:49ri @
>   348032839-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:49(anonymous
>   function) @ 348032839-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:14Cj.v @
>   348032839-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:75ph @
>   348032839-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:30kh @
>   348032839-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:31(anonymous
>   function) @ 348032839-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:28

Comment: Where are you getting the error? If it's an `unexpected end of unput` error, it should tell you exactly what is giving you this error in the console, correct?

Comment: There is, went ahead and added that into my post.

Comment: This looks like an issue with a missing end brace: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of inputn.extend.globalEval @

Comment: Where is there a missing brace though? I'll admit that my paste cut off the <script> brace, but for the squiggly brackets they are there.

Comment: Try using a pretty printer or node to check the syntax of the file